# swag (slang) -- what does this word really mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

Source: [Russia Is On A 'Holy Mission' And The West Doesn't Get It](http://www.businessinsider.com/russia-is-on-a-holy-mission-and-the-west-doesnt-get-it-2015-1)

Example:

> In his State of the Union address, Obama displayed similar **swag** and bluster against both the Kremlin and congressional Republicans, seemingly without regard for any recent events. As the president explained: ...

I hear it a lot, but what does this slang word really mean?

Comment: Please don't make trivial edits to older questions. *Actually* and *really* are synonyms, and *used* can stay (there's no practical difference between *hear it used often* and *hear it often*).

Comment: @userr2684291 Okay. Got it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### UPDATE

February 01, 2018, the OED has recently added the word **swag** in its dictionary. *Oxford Online Dictionaries* [reports](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2018/01/30/oed-new-words-mansplain-hangry-snowflake/)

> A new entry has been added for ***swag*, derived from *swagger*, and used in slang to denote ‘bold self-assurance in style or manner’, or ‘an air of great self-confidence or superiority’**. The OED’s first citation for this particular sense comes from the track ‘December 4th’ on Jay-Z’s The Black Album (2003): ‘My self-esteem went through the roof, man. I got my swag.’ This is the fifth OED citation attributed to Jay-Z.

A glossarial example of the word from the previous year, in a self-described dictionary of hip-hop terminology, defined swag as simply ‘walk’.

### ORIGINAL POST

(October 12, 2016)

“Obama displayed similar **swag and bluster** …”

In his sixth State of the Union Address, President Obama said:

> <sub>We’re upholding the principle that bigger nations can’t bully the small — by opposing Russian aggression, supporting Ukraine’s democracy and reassuring our NATO allies. Last year, as we were doing the hard work of imposing sanctions along with our allies, some suggested that Mr. Putin’s aggression was a masterful display of strategy and strength. Well, today, it is **America that stands strong and united with our allies**, while Russia is isolated, with its economy in tatters. **That’s how America leads** — **not with bluster, but with persistent, steady resolve** (Applause).</sub>
>   <sub><sup>From [whitehouse.gov](https://www.whitehouse.gov/), January 20, 2015</sup></sub>

The ***swag*** appears to be a clipped form of  *[**swagger**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/swagger)*, which the article accuses President Obama of doing.  In the speech, the ‘swag’ refers to America standing strong, unafraid of Russia, and determined to enforce sanctions. The *bluster*, according to the author, is Obama's words whose tone was possibly concealing a threat to Putin. The fact that Obama asserted America did not engage in *bluster*, was telling the audience that America was not afraid of taking further action if necessary.

> **bluster**
>   [talk intended to seem important or threatening but which is not taken
>
>    seriously and has little effect](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bluster)
>
> **swagger**
>   *[to walk, esp. with a swinging movement, in a way that
>
>   shows that you are confident and think you are important](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/swagger)*
>   <sub><sup>Cambridge Dictionary</sup></sub>

Comment: If you were a lexicographer, would you add the word **swag** and the definition "a clipped form of *swagger*" to your dictionary based on this one attestation?

Comment: So far no one has provided any evidence that that word **swag** is a clipped form of **swagger**.  It could be a malapropism. Or it could be a bit of new slang. Or it could be authorial license. We don't know at this point.  IMO, conjectures should be offered as comments, not answers.

Comment: On the off chance someone else thinks my answer is presumptuous, I am at pains to point out the following: `The swag appears to be a clipped form of swagger, ` I said "appears" for a good reason. There's nothing dogmatic in my answer.

Comment: When I read "swag" I assumed they really meant "swagger", but I'm old so my slang is a bit outdated. [snopes.com](http://www.snopes.com/language/acronyms/swag.asp) claims *It is instead a corruption of the Scandinavian svagga, meaning "to rock unsteadily or lurch" and entered the English language in the 13th or 14th century. [Etymology online](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=swagger) echoes snopes and says the earliest recorded usage of swagger was in Midsummer Night's Dream.

Comment: Hmm this is interesting though: http://rturk.expertscolumn.com/article/difference-between-having-swagger-and-having-swag Apparently "swag" is different from "swagger". *Though it may seem that the word "swag" came as a result of abbreviating the word "swagger," the two have seemingly taken on much different definitions recently.* The source isn't authoritative though.

Comment: @ColleenV [She Got That Swag](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/souljaboy/shegotthatswag.html) lyrics NSFW !

Comment: @ColleenV that last link of yours is actually worth posting, it's relevant and pertinent to the OP. You should post an answer!

Comment: @Mari-LouA If I get some time to find some corroboration, I may write an answer. I worry about basing an entire answer on some random blog post I found, especially since I'm more "[The Cramps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cramps)" than "Souljaboy" :)

Answer (score 3):

Another use of *swag* in the same story:

> Obama likewise seems to think that a bit of swag, plus a public taunt, aimed at Putin when the former KGB man is down on his luck will have the desired geopolitical effect.

The word actually means what the dictionary definitions, including the one posted by CopperKettle, say it means. However, sometimes authors are unaware of what words actually mean (how other people use them). If the author is using *swag* as short for *swagger* he is either using it in error or trying to use it to have two meanings at once. In either case his usage is so esoteric it escapes the common reader. A third possibility is that I am unaware that *swag* is short for *swagger*.

Comment: I'm not completely sure yet, but I did some googling and "swag and bluster" appears to be a fixed phrase. This might be a case where reference works have it wrong, and the phrase has to be understood as creative rhetoric, drawing the listener's feeling for the language. I need to look into it more, though. If I find something, I'll post a new answer. (Or you might beat me to it.)

Answer (score -3):

there is a difference between swag & swagg. What the writer ought to use here is swagg, which means style, something that sets you apart from the others.

Answer (score -3):

My understanding of the word swag means fool materialistic cool stuff, features and promotional warez. For e.g. I went to a concert and bought some of the swag. Hats, T-Shirts, Key Chain etc. In addition e.g. I went to a live TV show recording and the audience members were given a swag bag.

Answer (score -4):

Swag generally means to have or do something that is "cool" features. This is term is often used to describe a person i.e.: Your example. S.W.A.G stands for stuff we all get, and generally describes give-aways such as samples or trials, at conventions or events.

Comment: This is what _swag_ generally means, but I don't think this is the right meaning for the question. Obama was displaying free stuff and giveaway samples in his State of the Union address??

Comment: I gave two meaning that was the second one.

Comment: Obama was displaying cool features in his State of the Union address??

Comment: The first part says it also means to do or act cool

Comment: Obama was acting cool in his State of the Union address?? It might help if you included in your answer an explanation of why this meaning makes sense in the context provided in the question.

Comment: I believe this answer indicates the correct meaning of *swag*, as does the wiki dictionary source posted by @CopperKettle. It seems to me the author of the article cited by the OP is using the word incorrectly (not in accordance with how everyone else uses it).

Comment: Swag as an abbreviation is different from the word I know I said both in my answer!

Comment: No, swag is not an acronym. http://www.snopes.com/language/acronyms/swag.asp

Answer (score -5):

'SWAG'  is the small bundle tied to a stick with one posseions in it , ie - AUS
A jolly SWAG man" a drifter. Also what a 'house breaker'US, 'burglar'UK, a SACK used to carry my...er...his loot in.

Comment: This answer does not explain how this meaning works in the context of the sentence in the question.

Comment: While this is a correct definition of swag, it is not the one used in the context of the quotation in the question.