# What is the meaning of swagger and swag?

Tags: vocabulary

I hear this word more often nowadays. 
Can someone native explain what is the meaning of swag.

The dictionary says "goods or money obtained illegally." But I don't think the following sentence implies that.

Example:

> It's my swag.
>
> You Ain't Got No Swag.

Comment: What was the context in which you found those sentences? Slang and jargon are often highly dependent on context, and the same word or phrase can have completely different meanings in different contexts.

Comment: Did you look up any web search engine such as Google?

Comment: _You Ain't Got No Swag_ is not a sentence – not the way you've capitalized it. It's a title.

Comment: @laugh - [Evidently, the OP did](https://www.google.com/search?q=meaning+of+swag).

Comment: Here's your answer: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48093/swag-slang-what-does-this-word-really-mean

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=SWAG