# The antonym of "diss"

Tags: word-request, slang, antonyms

I learn that 'diss' is a shortened version of "disrespect"
[Urban Dictionary: diss](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=diss)

> For example, try to diss me, man.

What's the opposite of it?
I searched 'spect' as shorthand for 'respect'.
Nevertheless, it does not feel as strong and smart as 'diss'

Note:
'Diss' is a extremely popular in China as cyberspeak for joking with each other.

Comment: That Chinese usage sounds like a new usage. Please provide an example sentence.

Comment: surely, if its an abbreviation, it should be spelled `"dis"`. Bare respek.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

My first thought was *to give someone **props***:

> - [give props to (one)](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+props+to)
>     To praise one and show them respect. *Thank you, but I have to give props to Jeanne, who organized this entire event for us.*
>     (TFD)
> - [props](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/props)
>     noun, ( usually used with a singular verb) Slang.
>
>   1. proper or due respect or recognition; credit:
>        I give him props for putting up with annoying customers.
>
>   (Dictionary.com)

That's well-known here in the US. There's a relevant post on ELU: [What's the etymology of “props”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73636/whats-the-etymology-of-props)

Notice that *props* itself is not used as a verb in this sense. We don't **prop* or **props someone* to mean that we praise them.

Comment: Yes, this is likely the best answer.  Note the current (or at least, not too old) slang for **"great respect"** would be **"mad props"**.

Comment: +1 I'd say the actual antonym is the positive, **rispek'**, but this is idiomatic.

Answer (score 18):

[Kudos](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/kudos) is originally used to praise and honor someones achievements, but is also used to show [respect](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kudos) in popular culture nowadays.

For example, you could congratulate your friend on passing a test by saying:

> Kudos to you for passing that test! That is quite a feat.

Be mindful that *kudos* is a singular form, even though it looks like a plural.

Comment: I always thought it was one of those nouns that is always plural, like *pajamas* or *cahoots*.  You can't give someone a single *kudo*, only two or more (even if they deserve only one).

Comment: @andrew:  kudos (from the Greek κῦδος - fame or glory) is uncountable. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/kudos

Comment: The meaning is right, but the social context is quite different. That is, the kind of situations in which you'd say "diss" are not the ones you'd say "kudos."

Comment: @Andrew or _chinos_. https://www.penny-arcade.com/comic/2016/03/18

Comment: Kudos used to be more commonplace on the internet than it is nowadays, and was definitely used to in situations where _respect_ would have worked as well.

Comment: Some web forums have created the horrible, horrible back-formation *kudo*, meaning an upvote or 'like' for a post. Eeuurgh.

Answer (score 15):

[Big-up](http://grammarist.com/usage/big-ups/) or Big-ups is used to acknowledge respect

Comment: Never heard of this one.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas, it's pretty common in the UK, particularly in the 1990's - 2000's.

Comment: Ali G is also fond of using this expression: Keep it real. Yo, **big up yourself**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rddtw6uMNoo#t=20m36s

Answer (score 13):

The term *diss* is certainly slang. All dictionaries that I checked list it as such. So, the opposite of it should probably also be a slang word. Thus, one possible antonym of the word *diss* that you might consider would be the term [**respek**](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=respek) (see definition #4 in Urban Dictionary) which was popularized in the early 2000s by the satirical fictional character Ali G portrayed by British comedian Sacha Baron Cohen. And it can definitely be used as an inside term (a term that's typically understood only by people who know certain facts and context).

Examples:

> Stop dissing me, man. Instead, show me some **respek**.
>
> — I nailed his ass five times in a row in Warcraft today.
>   — Total **respek**, man!

Ali G talks about how respek is important (don't forget it's comedy): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vqtg_JFGh6I

[image]

Comment: *Respek* is not found Cambridge, Oxford, or Meriam-Webster Dictionary. It is therefore not a valid word, IMO.

Comment: And what does that mean? It can't be used? A lot of slang terms are not found in dictionaries.

Comment: Also, I don't think it's a [slang](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/slang); it's just an eye-dialect (if not merely a misspelling) of 'respect', IMO.

Comment: But the question is can *respek* be considered the opposite of *diss*? I certainly think it can. Everything else is details.

Comment: Like most slang, there will be a group of people that know it well. Respek, (with a certain emphasis, and use as a one word sentence), was a common word in Caribbean communities of a certain age in the UK. It is probably where Ali-G got it from, and it certainly answers the original question!

Comment: @user178049 Dictionaries are not the definers of language, they are the references of language - new words enter the dictionary all the time. "Hangry" only entered this year for instance. http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-42870791

Comment: @user178049 - I think that's a pretty shabby litmus test for determining what is or isn't a "valid word". I remember when _d'oh_ wasn't in the dictionary – but it's there now. Same with _qubit_.

Comment: @J.R. It's interesting that this came up, because just recently MariLou updated  [her "swag" answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/106340) to let us know that OED added an entry for "swag". If a word has to have a dictionary entry to be "valid" to offer as an answer to a question about slang, it would exclude a lot of modern slang, eye-dialect variations, etc. Those words might not be useful for a business interview, but they can be fun to try out in a more informal setting (or could help a future visitor understand something they heard or saw that isn't in their dictionary!).

Comment: @ColleenV - Every word has an "incubation period" where it gets used in the vernacular before it gets added into dictionaries. Only time will tell if _respek_ gets recognized one day (and I wouldn't be surprised if it never does). Nevertheless, our learners don't need to be told that only words in Oxford, Cambridge, or M-W are true words; thankfully, our language is much less restrictive and far too wonderful for that.

Answer (score 4):

I have heard ‘spec’ used in UK as a positive reinforcement of a person’s integrity, a shortened form of ‘respect’.

Comment: Do you have a source that supports your answer?

Comment: @LarsMekes It's very difficult sometimes to find a written citation for newish spoken slang. It might help to add an example sentence to the answer that illustrates how 'spec is used.

Answer (score 2):

You mention that diss is slang.  You didn't mention whether you wanted your result to be slang.  Here are some less slangy results:

- prop (as in "prop him up", slightly different than "give him props" as noted in [Max's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/155551/17653))
- give kudos [to] (again, a variation of usage from another answer, this time [Lars Mekes's answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/155552/17653))
- several others: compliment, envy / be jealous, follow, praise (or "singing his praises"), glorify, honor, elevate, dignify, give homage, venerate

Comment: I'm not sure how common "give homage" is, but "pay homage" is what I usually hear in American movies.

Answer (score 0):

"Stroking" is verbally boosting someone's ego, with praise or gushing admiration or fawning.

It seems to me the perfect absolute antonym to "diss", which isn't just about disrespect, it's about trying to tear someone down and damage their ego.

> "Bob, that was really the best, your stuff is the best, you're the best."
>
> "Aww, Betty, thanks but you really don't have to stroke me like that."

Comment: I'd recommend against this one, as I can think of two possible misunderstandings of "stroke me like that". The first has to do with petting as with a cat, and the second isn't fit to print.

Comment: @MathieuK. That's the point. The word is SUPPOSED to evoke that double entendre. (At least that has always been the intention when I hear it.)

Comment: No, it's fine to leave it at stroking as in a cat. Plus, I don't think we need to worry about the sensibilities of people who are already having a conversation in which the word "diss" is being used.

Answer (score 0):

**Word**

Sometimes: word up

From generally the same culture as 'diss' comes the single word exclamation: word, signifying respect or agreement with the person spoken to.

[The Urban Dictionary definition of "word" is](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Word)

> "Word" has no single meaning, but is used to convey a casual sense of affirmation, acknowledgement, agreement, or to indicate that something has **impressed you favorably**.

Comment: Can't be dropped into place except in such short exclamations as *Diss!* *Burn!* (vs) *Word!* For instance: "Why do you always *word* John?"

Comment: Sure it can. People have been verbing nouns and interjections for ages. "Diss" itself is such a phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

**Diss** can be used as a verb or as a noun. Similarly, it's antonym should be the same.

Complement is the closest word I can think of.

> He dissed me. He complimented me.
>
> That's a bad diss. That's a good complement.

Comment: I don't think [complement](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/complement) ( Something that completes, makes up a whole, or brings to perfection) means what you think it means. Perhaps you meant [compliment](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/compliment)?